# Como alinear botones que estan dentro de un elemento LI

Tags: javascript, html, css, css-grid-layout, selectores-css

necesito ayuda con un poco de CSS para botones dentro de un elemento "LI", resulta que tengo un genrador de historial en JS;

```
li.appendChild(document.createTextNode(Historial[index].Root+" MINOR | "+progresion));
      var buttonP = document.createElement("button");
      var buttonD = document.createElement("button");
      buttonP.innerHTML = "";

      var i = document.createElement("i");
      i.className = "gg-play-button-o" 
      buttonP.className = "btn-play";
      buttonP.appendChild(i);


      
      buttonD.innerHTML = "";
      var i = document.createElement("i");
      i.className = "gg-software-download" 
      buttonD.className = "btn-play";
      buttonD.appendChild(i);
      li.appendChild(buttonP);
      li.appendChild(buttonD);
      buttonP.onclick=function(){ Sonar(Historial[index])  };
      buttonD.onclick=function(){DescargarMidi(Historial[index])};
      
      ul.appendChild(li);
```

esto genera un historial como el siguiente:[image: historial generado]

sin embargo me gustaria que se parezca mas a algo como esto:
[image: como deberia ser]

el codigo css del historial y de la lista es el siguiente:

```
@import url('https://css.gg/software-download.css');
@import url('https://css.gg/play-button-o.css');

#historial {
    display: inline-block;
    text-align: left;
    background-color: aliceblue;
    width: 800px;
}
.DivHistorial{
    text-align: center;
}
.btn-play {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
width: 100px;
height: 100px;
}
```

Comment: Sería ideal que agregues el código html para poder ver bien como es la estructura, donde se están creando los ul, li y otros elementos como "Historial".. De otra manera es imposible entender lo que intentas hacer.
En cuanto a alinearlos, debería bastar con envolver textos y botones en un div y a ese div que los encierra aplicarle display: flex.
Te sugiero leer [ask], se sugiere subir un código minimo verificable.

Answer (score 0):

Lo ideal sería incluir el código que genera ese código Javascript para saber dónde se aplican los selectores *#historial* y *.DivHistorial*, pero para conseguir alinear cada elemento de la lista como pretendes, podrías añadirle al ***li*** que corresponda algo así:

```
li {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    align-items: center; /* Alinea verticalmente en el centro respecto al eje horizontal */
}

li .btn-play {
    margin-left: 1rem; /* Sirve para aplicar un margen a la izquierda del botón, evitando que queden pegados entre ellos y al texto */
}
```